# ViewChild error:Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554) core.d.ts(8054, 47): An argument for 'opts' was not provided

Tags: angular, nativescript, viewchild

At this line of the following code `@ViewChild('myListView') listViewComponent: RadListViewComponent;` I get the this error message:

> Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554) core.d.ts(8054, 47): An
> argument for 'opts' was not provided.

As I am a new learner just following a tutorial from 2017, I have no idea about why this happens and how can I fix it? But it seems the implementation of `ViewChild()` decorator is changed though I don't know how to adapt my code to fix it?

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core'; 
import { View } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/core/view';
import { FavoriteService } from '../services/favorite.service'; 
import { Dish } from '../shared/dish'; 
import { ListViewEventData, RadListView } from 'nativescript-ui-listview'; 
import { RadListViewComponent } from 'nativescript-ui-listview/angular'; 
import { ObservableArray } from 'tns-core-modules/data/observable-array'; 
import { DrawerPage } from '../shared/drawer/drawer.page'; 
import { confirm } from "tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs"; 
import { Toasty, ToastDuration, ToastPosition } from 'nativescript-toasty';


@Component({ 
    selector: 'app-favorites', 
    moduleId: module.id, 
    templateUrl: './favorites.component.html', 
    styleUrls: ['./favorites.component.css'] 
}) 
export class FavoritesComponent extends DrawerPage implements OnInit {
    
    favorites: ObservableArray<Dish>; 
    errMess: string;

    @ViewChild('myListView') listViewComponent: RadListViewComponent;
    
    constructor(private favoriteservice: FavoriteService, 
        private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,        
        @Inject('BaseURL') private BaseURL) { 
            super(changeDetectorRef); 
        }


    ngOnInit() { 
        this.favoriteservice.getFavorites() 
        .subscribe(favorites => this.favorites = new ObservableArray (favorites), 
        errmess => this.errMess = errmess); 
    }

    deleteFavorite(id: number) { 
        console.log('delete', id);

        let options = { 
            title: "Confirm Delete", 
            message: 'Do you want to delete Dish '+ id, 
            okButtonText: "Yes", 
            cancelButtonText: "No", 
            neutralButtonText: "Cancel" 
        };

        confirm(options).then((result: boolean) => { 
            if(result) {
                this.favorites = null;
                this.favoriteservice.deleteFavorite(id) 
                .subscribe(favorites => { 
                    //const toast = new Toasty("Deleted Dish "+ id, "short", "bottom" ); 
                    //toast.show();
                    const toasty = new Toasty({ text: "Deleted Dish "+ id })
                    .setToastDuration(ToastDuration.SHORT)
                    .setToastPosition(ToastPosition.BOTTOM)
                    //.setTextColor(new Color('white'))
                    //.setBackgroundColor('#ff9999')
                    .show();  
                    this.favorites = new ObservableArray(favorites); 
                }, 
                errmess => this.errMess = errmess);
            } 
            else { 
                console.log('Delete cancelled'); 
            }
        });
    }    

    public onCellSwiping(args: ListViewEventData) { 
        var swipeLimits = args.data.swipeLimits; 
        var currentItemView = args.object; 
        var currentView;

        if(args.data.x > 200) {

        } 
        else if (args.data.x < -200) {
        }
    }

    public onSwipeCellStarted(args: ListViewEventData) { 
        var swipeLimits = args.data.swipeLimits; 
        var swipeView = args['object'];
        var leftItem = swipeView.getViewById<View>('mark-view'); 
        var rightItem = swipeView.getViewById<View>('delete-view'); 
        swipeLimits.left = leftItem.getMeasuredWidth(); 
        swipeLimits.right = rightItem.getMeasuredWidth(); 
        swipeLimits.threshold = leftItem.getMeasuredWidth()/2;
    }
    public onSwipeCellFinished(args: ListViewEventData) {
    }

    public onLeftSwipeClick(args: ListViewEventData) { 
        console.log('Left swipe click'); 
        this.listViewComponent.listView.notifySwipeToExecuteFinished(); 
    }

    public onRightSwipeClick(args: ListViewEventData) { 
        this.deleteFavorite(args.object.bindingContext.id); 
        this.listViewComponent.listView.notifySwipeToExecuteFinished(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554) core.d.ts(8064, 47): An argument for 'opts' was not provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56669922/expected-2-arguments-but-got-1-ts2554-core-d-ts8064-47-an-argument-for-o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In v8 ViewChild syntax changed CHANGELOG says

> "Core: In Angular version 8, it's required that all @ViewChild and
>   @ContentChild queries have a 'static' flag specifying whether the
>   query is 'static' or 'dynamic'. The compiler previously sorted queries
>   automatically, but in 8.0 developers are required to explicitly
>   specify which behavior is wanted. This is a temporary requirement as
>   part of a migration; see
>   https://v8.angular.io/guide/static-query-migration for more details."

I recommend to use https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md to update

Answer (score 9):

If you are using angular8 the `ViewChild()` decorator changed: https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration, so you are missing the `static`parameter
`@ViewChild('myListView', {static: false}) listViewComponent: RadListViewComponent;`