# Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554) index.ts(54, 112): An argument for 'arg1' was not provided

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, stripe-payments

[I've copied the firebase stripe GitHub example index.js](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/stripe/functions/index.js) and have been fixing the errors which pop up from hosting the code in my index.ts (typescript) file. The error I have left is the following:

> Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554) index.ts(54, 112): An argument for 'arg1' was not provided.

It's about this line (there are multiple instances although this should not matter to the solution):

```
       await snap.ref.set(paymentMethod);
```

**How do I fix this error?** I have come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56669922/expected-2-arguments-but-got-1-ts2554-core-d-ts8064-47-an-argument-for-o), but it did not solve my problem.

```
 'use strict';

 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 admin.initializeApp();
 const { Logging } = require('@google-cloud/logging');
 const logging = new Logging({
   projectId: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
 });
 
 const { Stripe } = require('stripe');
 const stripe = new Stripe(functions.config().stripe.secret, {
   apiVersion: '2020-08-27',
 });
 
 /**
  * When a user is created, create a Stripe customer object for them.
  *
  * @see https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse#web-create-customer
  */
 exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user: { email: any; uid: any; }) => {
   const customer = await stripe.customers.create({ email: user.email });
   const intent = await stripe.setupIntents.create({
     customer: customer.id,
   });
   await admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).set({
     customer_id: customer.id,
     setup_secret: intent.client_secret,
   });
   return;
 });
 
 /**
  * When adding the payment method ID on the client,
  * this function is triggered to retrieve the payment method details.
  */
 exports.addPaymentMethodDetails = functions.firestore
   .document('/stripe_customers/{userId}/payment_methods/{pushId}')
   .onCreate(async (snap: { data: () => { (): any; new(): any; id: any; }; ref: { set: (arg0: { error: any; }, arg1: { merge: boolean; } | undefined) => any; parent: { parent: { set: (arg0: { setup_secret: any; }, arg1: { merge: boolean; }) => any; }; }; }; }, context: { params: { userId: any; }; }) => {
     try {
       const paymentMethodId = snap.data().id;
       const paymentMethod = await stripe.paymentMethods.retrieve(
         paymentMethodId
       );
       await snap.ref.set(paymentMethod);
       // Create a new SetupIntent so the customer can add a new method next time.
       const intent = await stripe.setupIntents.create({
         customer: `${paymentMethod.customer}`,
       });
       await snap.ref.parent.parent.set(
         {
           setup_secret: intent.client_secret,
         },
         { merge: true }
       );
       return;
     } catch (error) {
       await snap.ref.set({ error: userFacingMessage(error) }, { merge: true });
       await reportError(error, { user: context.params.userId });
     }
   });
 
 /**
  * When a payment document is written on the client,
  * this function is triggered to create the payment in Stripe.
  *
  * @see https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse#web-create-payment-intent-off-session
  */
 
 // [START chargecustomer]
 
 exports.createStripePayment = functions.firestore
   .document('stripe_customers/{userId}/payments/{pushId}')
   .onCreate(async (snap: { data: () => { amount: any; currency: any; payment_method: any; }; ref: { parent: { parent: { get: () => any; }; }; set: (arg0: { error: any; }, arg1: { merge: boolean; } | undefined) => any; }; }, context: { params: { pushId: any; userId: any; }; }) => {
     const { amount, currency, payment_method } = snap.data();
     try {
       // Look up the Stripe customer id.
       const customer = (await snap.ref.parent.parent.get()).data().customer_id;
       // Create a charge using the pushId as the idempotency key
       // to protect against double charges.
       const idempotencyKey = context.params.pushId;
       const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create(
         {
           amount,
           currency,
           customer,
           payment_method,
           off_session: false,
           confirm: true,
           confirmation_method: 'manual',
         },
         { idempotencyKey }
       );
       // If the result is successful, write it back to the database.
       await snap.ref.set(payment);
     } catch (error) {
       // We want to capture errors and render them in a user-friendly way, while
       // still logging an exception with StackDriver
       console.log(error);
       await snap.ref.set({ error: userFacingMessage(error) }, { merge: true });
       await reportError(error, { user: context.params.userId });
     }
   });
 
 // [END chargecustomer]
 
 /**
  * When 3D Secure is performed, we need to reconfirm the payment
  * after authentication has been performed.
  *
  * @see https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-synchronously#web-confirm-payment
  */
 exports.confirmStripePayment = functions.firestore
   .document('stripe_customers/{userId}/payments/{pushId}')
   .onUpdate(async (change: { after: { data: () => { (): any; new(): any; status: string; id: any; }; ref: { set: (arg0: any) => void; }; }; }, context: any) => {
     if (change.after.data().status === 'requires_confirmation') {
       const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.confirm(
         change.after.data().id
       );
       change.after.ref.set(payment);
     }
   });
 
 /**
  * When a user deletes their account, clean up after them
  */
 exports.cleanupUser = functions.auth.user().onDelete(async (user: { uid: any; }) => {
   const dbRef = admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers');
   const customer = (await dbRef.doc(user.uid).get()).data();
   await stripe.customers.del(customer.customer_id);
   // Delete the customers payments & payment methods in firestore.
   const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
   const paymetsMethodsSnapshot = await dbRef
     .doc(user.uid)
     .collection('payment_methods')
     .get();
   paymetsMethodsSnapshot.forEach((snap: { ref: any; }) => batch.delete(snap.ref));
   const paymentsSnapshot = await dbRef
     .doc(user.uid)
     .collection('payments')
     .get();
   paymentsSnapshot.forEach((snap: { ref: any; }) => batch.delete(snap.ref));
 
   await batch.commit();
 
   await dbRef.doc(user.uid).delete();
   return;
 });
 
 /**
  * To keep on top of errors, we should raise a verbose error report with Stackdriver rather
  * than simply relying on console.error. This will calculate users affected + send you email
  * alerts, if you've opted into receiving them.
  */
 
 // [START reporterror]
 
 function reportError(err: { stack: any; }, context = {}) {
   // This is the name of the StackDriver log stream that will receive the log
   // entry. This name can be any valid log stream name, but must contain "err"
   // in order for the error to be picked up by StackDriver Error Reporting.
   const logName = 'errors';
   const log = logging.log(logName);
 
   // https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/ref_v2beta1/rest/v2beta1/MonitoredResource
   const metadata = {
     resource: {
       type: 'cloud_function',
       labels: { function_name: process.env.FUNCTION_NAME },
     },
   };
 
   // https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/ErrorEvent
   const errorEvent = {
     message: err.stack,
     serviceContext: {
       service: process.env.FUNCTION_NAME,
       resourceType: 'cloud_function',
     },
     context: context,
   };
 
   // Write the error log entry
   return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
     log.write(log.entry(metadata, errorEvent), (error: any) => {
       if (error) {
         return reject(error);
       }
       return resolve();
     });
   });
 }
 
 // [END reporterror]
 
 /**
  * Sanitize the error message for the user.
  */
 function userFacingMessage(error: { type: any; message: any; }) {
   return error.type
     ? error.message
     : 'An error occurred, developers have been alerted';
 }
```

Full error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tried this but as per the typescript hint. this function accepts 2 arguments.

1. `arg0` of type object which has property `error` of type `any`.
2. `arg1` of type object which has property `merge` of type `boolean` or `undefined`.

So you need to call it something like this if setting error.

```
 snap.ref.set({ error: new Error("Error") }, { merge: true }); // second arg can be merge as true/false or undefined
```

if not setting error

```
snap.ref.set({ error: null }, { merge: true }); // second arg can be merge as true/false or undefined

snap.ref.set({ error: null }, undefined);
```

Comment: I have this line: set({ error: new Error("Error") }, { merge: true });//set(payment) as u can see the payment data is commented out. Hoow do I include it in the call? Couold u show as an example above?

Comment: What is the value of `paymentMethod` which is passed into `await snap.ref.set(paymentMethod);` method, couldn't see it in the screenshot. If it's like `const paymentMethod = { arg1: { error: new Error("Error") }, arg2: { merge: true }}` then use it like this `await snap.ref.set(paymentMethod.arg1, paymentMethod.arg2);`, else you can directly pass the object itself like i showed above `snap.ref.set({ error: new Error("Error") }, { merge: true });`

Comment: its in the code in the question but here it is to make easy: await stripe.paymentIntents.create(
         {
           amount,
           currency,
           customer,
           payment_method,
           off_session: false,
           confirm: true,
           confirmation_method: 'manual',
         },
         { idempotencyKey }
       )

Edit: I think any

Comment: Ok sorry, I see what you mean now.

Comment: I see in the code now, can you try this `await snap.ref.set(...payment);`